# Cannot Click Button in Datagridview Cell (Winforms)

Tags: c#, winforms, button, datagridview

I have a data-bound `DataGridView` which I want to manipulate through the use of buttons which appear in the `DataGridView` next to the contents of the row they will affect (pictured below). Each row contains a `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` as well a `DataGridViewButtonColumn`, both of which I want to show at all times.

When a mouse is hovered over a row, additional buttons appear to rearrange the data in the list, seen in row 2 (index 1) of the picture.

[image: DataGridView with Example Data, Button Column, and Embedded Controls]

The dynamic buttons have `Button.Click` events to perform the desired actions. However, simply hovering over a row and clicking on a button does not call the `OnClick` method. The buttons do not highlight when hovered over or produce a clicking animation as is typical. If the mouse hovers over the static button in the `DataGridViewButtonColumn` of the same row, the dynamic buttons suddenly perform as desired, interacting with mouse hovering and `OnClick` event. Moving the mouse to another row resets this behavior.

**How can I make the `OnClick` method properly trigger when a dynamic button is clicked without first interacting with static elements in the row?** I have tried giving focus programmatically to various controls with no success. I do not want the dynamic buttons to be additional columns. The dynamic buttons should be to be clicked simply by moving the mouse into the grid, without addition interaction with other components.

Thanks.

Relevant Code:

```
// Instantiation
{
    /* .... */

    // Dynamic button declarations
    Button deleteButton= new Button();
    deleteButton.Text = ""
    deleteButton.Click += (sender, e) => OnClick(sender, e, ButtonType.Delete);
    /* Repeat for remaining dynamic buttons */

    /* .... */

    // Set up grid columns

    // Column
    grid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    DataGridViewTextBoxColumn column = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
        {
            Name = "Condition",
            DataPropertyName = "Value",
            AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill
        };
    grid.Columns.Add(column);

    // Type
    DataGridViewButtonColumn num = new DataGridViewButtonColumn()
        {
            Name = "Type",
            Width = 40,
            DataPropertyName = "Type"
        };
    num.CellTemplate.Style.Font = new Font("Arial", 8, FontStyle.Italic);
    grid.Columns.Add(num);

    // Data binding
    grid.DataSource = (BindingList)data

    // Interaction with DataGridView
    grid.CellMouseEnter += (sender, e) => GridHover(sender, e);
    grid.CellMouseLeave += (sender, e) => GridLeave(sender, e);

    /* .... */
}

// Control methods

// Mouse hovering over row
protected void GridHover(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    int row = e.RowIndex;
    if (row >= 0 && row < ((DataGridView)sender).Rows.Count)
    {
        ((DataGridView)sender).Focus();

        ((DataGridView)sender).Controls.Add(deleteButton);
        deleteButton.Location = new Point(((DataGridView)sender).GetCellDisplayRectangle(0, row, true).Right - 20, ((DataGridView)sender).GetCellDisplayRectangle(0, row, true).Top);
        deleteButton.Size = new Size(20, ((DataGridView)sender).GetCellDisplayRectangle(0, row, true).Height);
        deleteButton.Show();
        /* Repeat for remaining dynamic buttons */
    }
}

// Mouse stops hovering over row
protected void GridLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    int row = e.RowIndex;
    if (row >= 0 && row < ((DataGridView)sender).Rows.Count)
    {
        upButton.Hide();
        /* Repeat for remaining dynamic buttons */
    }
}

// Mouse clicks dynamic button
protected void GridButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e, ButtonType buttonType)
{
    /* Program does not reach this point without first hovering over DataGridViewButtonColumn */
}
```

Comment: Not sure but I guess the mouse event model is being confused by your moving the button (to a location under the the cursor?) while the hover event is still being processed..

Comment: What mouse event model? The hover event executes once when the mouse enters a cell, and I click some time after entering the cell. Since the button is shown, the hover event has already completed.

Comment: You are right. Something is wrong with your buton(s). When I instead place a button on the form and on init nest it in the dgv and move it to your button location it works fine. Not sure what is missing; should be in the designer.cs file..

Comment: Looking in my designer.cs file, I'm not missing any properties that a button added through the designer has. In fact, if I place the buttons in another control, they work fine. It's something specific with the dgv.

Comment: When you tried replicating my issue, are you using a blank/manually filled DGV or are you using a data source? That might contribute to the issue.

Comment: My DGV is empty but I can reproduce the issue. The button doesn't have a TabIndex but that doesn't matter either. It seems to be a focus problem; but why this doesn't come up with other, not dynamically created buttons beats me..

Comment: Hm, funny: I didn't hide/show that other button; when I do that it stop working too..!?! - When logging out these events I find that they are called very very often. Looks unhealthy ;-)

Comment: Here are my findings, ca't pursue any longer. It seems to work with other buttons (not sure about the dynamic one) if I modify the enter and leave event like so: Enter: Abort when nor needed: `protected void GridHover(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
          DataGridView dgv = sender as DataGridView;
            if (dgv.CurrentCell == dgv[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex]) return;`

Comment: - and Leave: Abort, maybe the same but also when the mouse is over the button. ((this may actually be the real key(?!)) : `DataGridView dgv = sender as DataGridView;
if (dgv.CurrentCell == dgv[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex]) return;

Rectangle rb = dgv.RectangleToScreen(  deleteButton.Bounds);
if (rb.Contains(Control.MousePosition)) return;`

Comment: Yup, just confirmed: All you need it adding the rectangle check. This is similar to what I had at the back of my mind: the button should not be hidden when we enter it, which we do at the same time we leave the cell..

Comment: @TaW That works! Feel free to answer and I'll mark it as solved!

Comment: I don't write answers here any longer. Feel free to self-answer it; it is a useful issue and worth an answer imo..

Answer (score 0):

Per discussion with @TaW, the issue is that the `GridLeave` is called when the mouse hovered over the dynamic buttons. This behavior only exhibits itself when `Hide`/`Show` are called, as `GridLeave` and `GridEnter` are called in rapid succession, preventing the form from focusing on the buttons, and therefor preventing the buttons from being clicked.

The problem is resolved if the buttons are not hidden when the mouse hovers over them. Adding the following check at the beginning of `GridLeave` resolves the issue:

```
if ((sender as DataGridView).RectangleToScreen(upButton.Bounds).Contains(Control.MousePosition) ||
    (sender as DataGridView).RectangleToScreen(downButton.Bounds).Contains(Control.MousePosition) ||
    (sender as DataGridView).RectangleToScreen(deleteButton.Bounds).Contains(Control.MousePosition))
            return;
```